# pandas - cannot filter rows by a string that has a plus sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a csv file data and I need to filter out a some rows based on product name. I was able to do that for all but one string. This string includes a space and a + sign. Here is what I have tried.

```
 clean_ts = raw_ts[raw_ts['Product'].str.contains('AZF S+H') == False]
 clean_ts = raw_ts[raw_ts['Product'].str.contains('S+H') == False]
```

Both return the same number of rows.

Do I have to escape the + sign or something. I thought that since this is a sting it should be fine but I guess not.

Comment: [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) supports regex. You'll have to escape the `+`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either escape it with `\+` or pass in `regex=False`.

By default, `regex` is `True` in [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

> regex : bool, default True
>
> If True use re.search, otherwise use Python **in** operator

Comment: it works if I only filter by that string but if I do raw_ts[raw_ts['Product'].str.contains('S+H|Dues', regex=False) == False] it does not work. Also tried the same thing with /+

Comment: @user3088202 change `/+` to `\+` and try it again.

Comment: @user3088202 no problem. Note that `|` and `+` are both reserved operators for regular expression and you cannot pass in `regex=False` in this situation if you need `|`.